# AWS lambda api gateway with node.js express returns an error of "net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 200"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

The error occurs when my client sends a GET request to the node.js server hosted with AWS lambda api gateway. The server is expected to send back an array of objects with res.json({}). The weird part is that when i test with a response of object or an array of objects with lesser variables in it, it works. I have also tried to JSON.stringify() the array in the server side and JSON.parse() in the client but to no avail. Thanks in advance to everyone helping me and do guide me along as its my first time posting on StackOverflow.

Edit: However i have tried it with a curl command to the endpoint and it returns the json array without any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright everyone i found which part of my code caused the bug!

```
app.use(busboy());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(busboyBodyParser());
```

As i was playing around with file transfer before with the npm package 'Busboy', imported and used some packages associated with it. However, i forgotten to comment out these codes and thus, i believe it messed up the response body and got the error. Just to be clear this was in the node.js backend.